# How can I clone a workbook in Spire.XLS?

Tags: c#, excel, spire.xls

I have a `Spire.Xls.Workbook` object which I would like to clone. Since the class doesn't offer a `Clone` method I tried to create a new workbook and copy all existing worksheets over from the existing workbook. This is my code:

```
public void Clone(Workbook workbook, string fileName)
{
    var clone = new Workbook();

    // copy worksheets to List to be able to use foreach
    var worksheets = workbook.Worksheets
        .Cast<Worksheet>()
        .ToList();

    foreach (Worksheet worksheet in worksheets)
    {
        var clonedSheet = worksheet.Clone(worksheet.Parent);
        clone.Worksheets.Add((IWorksheet)clonedSheet);
    }

    clone.SaveToFile(fileName, ExcelVersion.Version2007);
}
```

The method completes without an error, the file gets created but it doesn't contain any of the cloned worksheets. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to create a clone of a `Workbook` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    clone.Worksheets.AddCopy(worksheets);
```

Answer (score 0):

[@DheerajMalik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921680) works well for `.xlsx` files. If you have `.xlsm` files then the macros will get lost. To work around this limitation, here's another approach:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Save the original to a memory stream
    workbook.SaveToStream(stream);

    // Create a new workbook and load the content from the memory stream
    var clone = new Workbook();
    clone.LoadFromStream(stream);
}
```